# How to create Multiple DSN (informix ODBC Driver) in client systems?

Tags: odbc, informix, dsn

I have 2 Informix databases running in parallel in a network. One is the primary server database and another one is the secondary server database. I need to create 2 DSN in client systems. one DSN is pointing to Primary anotherone pointing to secondary.From the client node, while saving the second DSN Automatically first DSN IP is changing into second DSN IP. So not able to connect two server at the same time.

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: Consider whether the Connection Manager can help you.  I'm not sufficiently familiar with ODBC on Windows to know what else is going on there.

Comment: Why not using a DSN-LESS connection? Rather than creating an ODBC DSN your application provides all the connections parameters in the connection string.
Something like:

`using (OdbcConnection InformixConnection = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)};SRVR=ids1210fc2;DB=stores7;UID=informix;PWD=mypassword;DLOC=en_US.819;CLOC=en_us.819;SERV=9089;PRO=onsoctcp;HOST=myhost"))`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   I have a doubt regarding the connection manager, I want to know how to connect the third-party application (scada) to the connection manager.